# Creating crosstab in ActiveReports 7 using XML datasource

Tags: xml, datasource, crosstab, activereports

I am trying to create a crosstab report in ActiveReport 7 and this seems to be possible through Visual Studio 2012 with a ActiveReports 7 Page Report (Toolbox > Matrix).
But my issue is trying to add an XML datasource to the report. This doesn't seem to be possible.

Then, on the other hand, if I create a new report using the ActiveReport end-user designer I can add an XML datasource, but not a crosstab element.

How can I create a crosstab report using an XML datasource?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by you that Matrix control can be used to create a [crosstab](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/Matrix%20Reports.html) tab report.

And in order to set the XML datasource for a report through Visual Studio, you may follow the steps provided in this [walkthrough](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/ReportswithXMLData.html).

Regards,
Mohita

Comment: ActiveReports7 is compatible with VS 2012 and under ideal conditions you should not face any issues.
It would be helpful if you could mention the exact error/problem that you are facing when working with ActiveReports7 in VS 2012

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't compatible, I said the walkthrough doesn't work for VS 2012. There is no error. Just no way to add an XML datasource to a report through Visual Studio 2012.